# Kolmogorov Zero One Law

Tags: probability, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

First Part :I want to prove that, if I have a sequence of independent Randomvariables $X_{n}$ and $T=\{\exists N \in \mathbb{N}:\forall n\geq N, X_{n}=X_{n+2}\}$, that $P(T)\in\{0,1\}$. I know that I have to show that T is in the Terminal sigma Algebra and then use Kolmogrovs Zero One Law. But I dont know how to show that T is in the terminal sigma Algebra.

Second Part: If $P(T)=1$ and the sequence is i.i.d, then $X_{i}$ is almost sure constant. How would I proof this ?

Comment: We could simplify a little first. Would it help if it were $X_n=X_{n+1}$ instead?

Comment: If $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}:\forall n\geq N, X_{n}=X_{n+2}$ is almost sure and if these $X_{n}$ and $X_{n+2}$ are independent then they must each take the same constant value with probability $1$ as otherwise you get a contradiction, and similarly $X_{n+2}$ and $X_{n+4}$ etc.   But I would have thought $X_{n+1}$ and $X_{n+3}$ etc. could be almost surely equal to a different constant, and it is having them all identically distributed which forces the same constant

Answer (score 1):

Define $\mathcal{F}_n:=\sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},\ldots)$. Then the tail $\sigma$-algebra is $\tau=\bigcap_{n\ge 1}\mathcal{F}_n$. It is clear that the event $T$ belongs to each $\mathcal{F}_n$ because it does not depend on $(X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_m)$ for any finite $m$, i.e.,
$$
T=\{\exists N: \forall n\ge N\vee m, X_{n}=X_{n+2}\}\in \mathcal{F}_m
$$
for any $m\ge 1$. Thus, $T\in \tau$ and by Kolmogorov's 0-1 law, $\mathsf{P}(T)\in \{0,1\}$.

Next, if $\mathsf{P}(T)=1$, then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcap_{m\ge n}\{X_m=X_{m+2}\}\right)=1.
$$
However, if $X_1$ is not a constant,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcap_{m\ge n}\{X_m=X_{m+2}\}\right)&\le \mathsf{P}\!\left(\bigcap_{m\ge n}\{X_{3m}=X_{3m+2}\}\right) \\
&=\prod_{m\ge n}\mathsf{P}(X_{3m}=X_{3m+2})=0.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

(1) Define $\mathscr{F}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma(X_k,k\ge n)$, $\mathscr{F}$ is a tail $\sigma$-algebra.
\begin{align*}
T&=\{\exists N\ge 1, \forall n\ge N, X_{n}=X_{n+2}\}\\
 &=\bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{n=N}^{\infty} \{X_{n}=X_{n+2}\},
\end{align*}
We know
$$T^c=\bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=N}^{\infty} \{X_{n}\ne X_{n+2}\}\in \mathscr{F},$$
$T\in \mathscr{F}$. By Kolmogorov's 0-1 law, $P(T)\in \{0, 1\}$.

(2) If $P(T)=1$, then $P(X_{n}\ne X_{n+2}, \text{i.o.})=0$. By $\{X_n, n\ge 1\}$ being i.i.d.
we abtain $P(X_{n}=X_{n+2})=1, \forall n\ge 1$.

If $X_1$ is not a constant, then there exists a Borel set $A\in \mathscr{B}^1$ such that
$P(X_1\in A)>0$ and $P(X_1\in A^c)>0$. Thus
$$P(X_1\in A, X_3\in A^c)\le P(X_1\ne X_3)=0.$$
Since $X_1, X_3$ are i.i.d.,
\begin{align*}
P(X_1\in A, X_3\in A^c)&=P(X_1\in A)P(X_3\in A^c)\\
                       &=P(X_1\in A)P(X_1\in A^c)>0.
\end{align*}
This is a contradiction. So, $X_1$ is a constant almost surely.